# Qt Custom Plugin Will Not Load - "Shared Library Not Found"

Tags: c++, qt, plugins

I am trying to build a QtPlugin architecture but I can't even get off the ground with the simplest plugin.  I created this plugin using the the examples and reading all over the websites, but no matter what I cannot load my plugin.

Upon calling `instance()` I get a  `0` and the `errorString()` says `could not find shared library.`

Comment: That error usually means you have passed an incorrect path to the loader.

Comment: *facepalm* yep totally forgot absolute file path.  Make that the answer so I can accept.

Comment: You wouldn't happen to know what this means `libpt_firstpluginimp.so: undefined symbol: _ZTV15SecondPluginImp`.  I am working towards an architecture that loads plugins which in turn can loads plugins.  My first step is to have a plugin which takes in "secondplugin.h"(interface) and "secondpluginimp.h" (implementation of interface) and has a 'SecondPlugin * cur_plugin = new SecondPluginImp()` as an initial test.

Comment: It usually means you have forgotten to define a static member in the source file, or you have declared a method as virtual but have forgotten to implement it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error usually means you have passed an incorrect path to the loader.